# React native SQLite insert statement not working

Tags: javascript, sqlite, react-native

I am trying to use SQLite with React native to insert some values into a table

In my main page I am creating the table like so...

```
db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql(
    `create table if not exists puzzles (
        id primary key not null, 
        level int not null, 
        image varchar(512) NOT NULL,
        imageSolution varchar(512) NULL,
        puzzleAnswer varchar(16) NULL,
        type varchar(16) NULL,
        availableLetters varchar(16) NULL,
        charactersGiven varchar(4) NULL);`
  );
});
```

In my page component I am trying to insert using the following:

```
    db.transaction(tx => {
      for (var puz of puzzlesFiltered) {
        tx.executeSql(
          `insert into
        puzzles (id, image, imageSolution, type, puzzleAnswer, level, charactersGiven, availableLetters)
        VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM puzzles WHERE id = ${
          puz.id
        })`,
          [
            puz.id,
            puz.image,
            puz.imageSolution,
            puz.type,
            puz.puzzleAnswer,
            puz.level,
            puz.charactersGiven,
            puz.charactersGiven
          ],
          (tx, results) => {
            console.log("Results", results.rowsAffected);
          },
          (err) => {
            console.error(err);
          }
        );
      }
    });
```

I am getting the following error message returned, which I have no idea what it means, can anyone help?

Also, is there a better way to insert an array, rather than looping through each row?

> [16:07:09] WebSQLTransaction {   "_complete": false,   "_error": null,
>   "_running": true,   "_runningTimeout": false,   "_sqlQueue": Queue {
>       "first": undefined,
>       "last": undefined,
>       "length": 0,   },   "_websqlDatabase": WebSQLDatabase {
>       "_currentTask": TransactionTask {
>         "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],
>         "readOnly": false,
>         "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
>         "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],
>       },
>       "_db": SQLiteDatabase {
>         "_closed": false,
>         "_name": "db.db",
>       },
>       "_running": true,
>       "_txnQueue": Queue {
>         "first": Object {
>           "item": TransactionTask {
>             "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],
>             "readOnly": false,
>             "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
>             "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],
>           },
>         },
>         "last": Object {
>           "item": TransactionTask {
>             "errorCallback": [Function anonymous],
>             "readOnly": false,
>             "successCallback": [Function anonymous],
>             "txnCallback": [Function anonymous],
>           },
>         },
>         "length": 1,
>       },
>       "version": "1.0",   }, }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your query is supported by SQLite.

You could try something like:

```
INSERT INTO puzzles
(id, image, imageSolution, type, puzzleAnswer, level, charactersGiven, availableLetters)
SELECT ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM puzzles WHERE id = ${puz.id})
```

Comment: i have some issue with sqlite, i create the insert fetch delete functions and for some  reason it doesn't work for me. can you help me please ?

Comment: that there is no insert into my db file .
do have facebook or something that i can connect with u to show u my problem.

Comment: Please rather open a dedicated SO question and share your code.